# How to use feature modules with lazy loading in Angular5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to load modules using lazy loading.
I work with Angular5.x, Angular material2.x and firebase.

**Current behavior**

`app-routing-module` and `feature-module-routing` don't work.
Even though, `scene module` loaded, doesn't show scene component.

**Expected behavior**

Both of routing modules should route right component.
After `scene module` loaded, could see the scene component which I declared in `scene module`.

**Explanation**

if url is empty, then redirect to `/auth`, so that user sign in.
So, I set router like this in `app-routing.module.ts`.

```js
//app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/auth', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent},
    {path: 'scene', loadChildren: './scene/scene.module#SceneModule'}
];
```

After user sign in, `auth.component.ts` check if user has a token or not.
If user has a token, then route to scene component.

Here's my codes

**auth.component.ts**

```js
export class AuthComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, public auth: AuthService, private relativeRouter: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.tokenCheck();
  }

  signIn() {
    this.auth.googleLogin().then(
      () => location.reload()
    );
  }

  tokenCheck() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if (token) {
      console.log('here');
      this.router.navigate(['../scene'], {
        relativeTo: this.relativeRouter
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**scene.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [
    SceneComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    TabComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SceneComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    TabComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: Why are you doing `this.router.navigate(['../scene']`? just use `['/scene']`

Comment: @Narm, I wanted to change url using `relativeTo`. And I changed like what you said, still it's not working

Comment: What does your `scene-router.module.ts` look like? I assume you set up lazy routes in your lazy loaded module right?

Comment: @Narm, Not in this project. Should I set router when I make a feature module? Actually, I tried to make nested lazy loading modules, but I couldn't make it. So I'm trying to do looks easy one first.

Comment: Actually after a little research I think you may be running into this Angular Bug. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17957

Comment: @Narm, Yeah, I exactly tried to do it, but it didn't work well. What should I do? Can't work as lazy loading with Angular? :(

Comment: Until the Angular team fixes that bug, you may need to skip lazy loading like that. I don't know any work arounds, so I will be of no help on this one. I am sorry. :/